# Nodejs ensure that API login happens only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, request

I wrote the following code for Node.js to connect to the API of my CMS. The API has to login once with username and password, and then proceeds to do requests with an access token. However, the access token has a limited time for which is it valid - afterwards the API has to login again and receive a new token.

When I do requests to the API, I always try to use the current token - if it is not valid anymore I will receive a 403 and trigger a new login, after which the initial request is then done again.

The problem here is, if multiple requests at the same time try to access the API, they all trigger a login - which results in several API sessions in the CMS, which is a bad thing. I thought I had that case handled with Promises, but apparently my code doesn't work as I imagined.

```
var api = {
    url: 'servername',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    token: null
};
var login_in_progress = true;
var loginPromise;
function loginApi() {
    login_in_progress = true;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request({
            uri: api.url + api.user + ',' + api.password,
            method: 'GET',
            json: true
        }, function (err, res, data) {
            if (!err && res.statusCode === 200) {
                api.token = data.token;
                login_in_progress = false;
                resolve(data);
            } else {
                login_in_progress = false;
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}

var getContent = function (query) {
    // Currently a login is running - wait till it's finished and then execute get
    // at least that was the idea - but does not seem to work
    if (login_in_progress && loginPromise) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            loginPromise
                .then(function () {
                    getContent(query)
                        .then(function (data) {
                            resolve(data);
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            reject(err);
                        });
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    } else {
        // Do the actual request
        // case 403 Api is logged out => reLogin
        loginPromise = loginApi();
        loginPromise
            .then(function () {
                getContent(query)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        resolve(data);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                reject(err)
            });
    }
}
```

Apparently, the check if an login is currently not running is not happening and the getContent function always runs into the else statement. I'm not even sure if my idea to check for a running login request would work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while the answers were helping me by thinking about the problem more, the actual problem was a different one:
I only checked for `login_inprogress` when `getContent` was started - not when the 403 returned.
This caused multiple API logins when requests were started at the same time.

The solution actually was quite simple:

```
// case 403 Api is logged out => reLogin
// check again if login is running NOW, only if not, start one
if(!login_in_progress){
    loginPromise = loginApi();
}
// Always attach to the loginPromise to redo the initial getContent
loginPromise
    .then(function () {
        getContent(query)
            .then(function (data) {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                reject(err);
            });
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        reject(err)
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this could work (nb: this is really "pseudo-code", not runnable code):

```
let authPromise = undefined;

function getContent(query) {
    if (!authPromise) {
        // no login pending - start one, then restart the whole function
        authPromise = login();
        return authPromise.then(() => getContent(query));
    } else {
        // login pending - wait for it, then make the real call
        // if the login promise already resolved, it won't wait
        return authPromise.then(() => makeAjaxRequest(query)).then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                // session expired - remove the state, and restart the whole function
                authPromise = undefined;
                return getContent(query);
            } else {
                // session still valid, return the API response
                return response;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with the only state being whether there's a `Promise` present.

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually would solve the problem of multiple logins when the API is logged out. Imagine there are 2 requests running against the API: the first one gets the 403, sets the authPromise to undefined and starts over - then the second request ALSO gets its 403 because it was still on the way with the old token - and ALSO sets authPromise to undefined and starts over. That would fail, no?

Comment: When I think about it, I need to check the token as well when the 403 occurs: Check if the token with which the request was made is still set inside the api object => new login necassary, set authRequest to undefined and set token to null. If the token already is null => login is already happening, use the authPromise which was changed in between by another request.

Thoughts?

Comment: re: your first comment - the first one doesn't get the 403 because there's no "login promise" at all yet, so it starts the login.    If a second query comes in before that finishes, it'll take the second code path, waiting for that initial login to also complete.    I didn't include any code relating to how the token itself is passed around.

Answer (score 1):

There were several things that could be corrected or simplified in your code. I simulated here the login and logout with a variable `testlogged` that replaces the 403 response in your original code, and the login delay with a timeout, just to demonstrate how you can do it with minimal code.

NOTES:

- You don't seem to need to have those nested promises in `getContent`. It's not really clear if this function uses another function to get content that returns a promise or if it needs to return a promise itself. This is not the same thing. For the second case you can see example 2.
- You need to be consistent about what `getContent` returns, be aware about what you want to be a promise. Either you pass a callback to `getContent` (example 1) or you use `then` on it (example 2).
- In example 1 it's quite simple to call `getContent` inside itself, but if it returns a promise I would prefer not, because it brings extra complexity, forcing to use `then` on it inside the function itself.
- For example 2 it's much clearer if `getContent` returns a new promise from the start, that wraps all the code

**EXAMPLE 1**

```js
var api = {
    url: 'servername',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    token: null
};
var testlogged = false;
var login_in_progress = true;
var loginPromise;
function loginApi() {
    login_in_progress = true;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('login OK');
            login_in_progress = false;
            testlogged = true;
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}

function getContent(query, callback) {
    // Currently a login is running - wait till it's finished and then execute get
    if (login_in_progress && loginPromise) {
        console.log('login in progress, waiting before getting content.. query: ' + query);
        loginPromise
            .then(function () {
                callback('got content OK (1) query: ' + query);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error('error: ', err);
            });
    } else {
        // Do the actual request
        if (!testlogged) {
            // case 403 Api is logged out => reLogin
            console.log('starting login.. query: ' + query);
            loginPromise = loginApi();
            //restarting function to put query in queue, saves code, but you could also do directly loginPromise.then(function () {...
            getContent(query, callback);
        } else {
            console.log('already logged');
            callback('got content OK (2) query: ' + query);
        }
    }
}

var theCallback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};

//doing first attempt while not logged
getContent('test', theCallback);
//trying with a concurrent attempt while still logging
getContent('test2', theCallback);
//simulating attempt while still being logged then after logout (waiting first that the 2 precendent attempts are finished)
setTimeout(function(){
    getContent('test3', theCallback);
}, 100);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('simulate log out');
    testlogged = false;
    getContent('test4', theCallback);
}, 100);
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```js
var api = {
    url: 'servername',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    token: null
};
var testlogged = false;
var login_in_progress = true;
var loginPromise;
function loginApi() {
    login_in_progress = true;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('login OK');
            login_in_progress = false;
            testlogged = true;
            resolve();
        }, 10);
    });
}

var getContent = function (query) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // Currently a login is running - wait till it's finished and then execute get
        if (login_in_progress && loginPromise) {
            console.log('login in progress, waiting before getting content.. query: ' + query);
            loginPromise
                .then(function () {
                    resolve('got content OK (1) query: ' + query);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
        } else {
            // Do the actual request
            if (!testlogged) {
                // case 403 Api is logged out => reLogin
                console.log('starting login.. query: ' + query);
                loginPromise = loginApi();
                loginPromise
                    .then(function () {
                        resolve('got content OK (1) query: ' + query);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    });
            } else {
                console.log('already logged');
                resolve('got content OK (2) query: ' + query);
            }
        }
    });
}

var theCallback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};

//doing first attempt while not logged
getContent('test').then(theCallback);
//trying with a concurrent attempt while still logging
getContent('test2').then(theCallback);
//simulating attempt while still being logged then after logout (waiting first that the 2 precendent attempts are finished)
setTimeout(function(){
    getContent('test3').then(theCallback);
}, 100);
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('simulate log out');
    testlogged = false;
    getContent('test4').then(theCallback);
}, 150);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not include the else part completely in the question - it actually returns a Promise as well. The only difference in your Example 2 code to mine is, that you return the Promise before the if/else while I return a Promise for the if and a Promise for the else.
You left out the interesting part though, but I checked with your code and it works: doing multiple requests at once should only trigger 1 login and resolve all afterwards. That's the problem I had - in my logs there were several logins when requests were done at the same time while the API was logged out.

Comment: I still wonder why I got the problem though, since my code is basically similar to Example 2 except that I did `if(){return Promise()}else{return Promise()}` instead of `return Promise({if(){}else{}})`. And that should not make a difference, no?

Comment: Ah I believe after reading the other answer and thinking about it I found the problem and why your code works: The actual request for getting the data is also async obviously, while in your sample it is just represented by resolve('text').

Comment: Then the problem might be rather in re-calling `getContent` inside itself in your code instead of using directly the async content request directly. Using console logs to test the vars could tell why. Is your content request just async with callback, or a promise?

Comment: getContent always returns a Promise. To do the actual requests to the API Inside getContent I'm using the request library which works with a callback. However, I'm pretty sure I figured out the problem as I wrote in a comment to the other answer. I need to re-check if a login is running when the 403 comes back, since multiple requests can be pending and all come back with 403 - and only the first one should trigger the re-login.

Comment: I think you have it, I'm currently thinking if this check should not be done in `loginApi` though..